# Is RTX 2050 compatible with PyTorch? Is it even CUDA-capable?

Tags: deep-learning, hardware, nvidia, cuda

The NVIDIA site does not list GTX 2050 as CUDA enabled, and does not list its compute capability. However, if you google "Is RTX 2050 cuda enabled", the first result you get is some NVIDIA forum moderator claiming that RTX 2050 being not listed as CUDA-enabled is a mistake, and that it is, in fact, CUDA-capable, just as "any NVIDIA GPU released in the last decade". The moderator then declares he is going to report the mistake to the guys who manage the site. However, this post is half a year long, and RTX 2050 is not listed yet. So I am asking, if anyone has **first-hand experience** training PyTorch models using RTX 2050 as CUDA.